# Changing the style of an inputbox for memos

Tags: ms-access, vba, user-input

I am a beginner at Microsoft Access trying to creating a database and one of the fields is a memo field. I would like to request user input for that field; However, the standard inputbox has a single line for the user to enter data, and although you can use that to add large amounts of text, it is not pleasing.

I want an inputbox that accepts memos so as the user inputs a paragraph of text, he can see the entire paragraph when he submits.

How would I do it using an inputbox and not a form? Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to use an inputbox as you want.  If possible, I suspect it would be impractical.  Why are you opposed to a form for this?

Comment: I do agree it is impractical, but I am having the user edit straight from a report and it would be nice not to switch between the report and a form.

Comment: You are an Access beginner.  You will find Access can be an effective RAD tool when you use its standard features.  If you insist on doing something in a non-standard way, you're buying much extra work for yourself.  And that may be extra challenging for a beginner.  If you're determined to go that route, all I can do is wish you luck.

Comment: I reckon @HansUp is giving you good advice. Try a form, you might enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are entering the data directly into the table.  If so you can simply hover over a line between two rows until you get the double arrows and click and drag.  When closing the table it will ask you if you want to save your changes.  if you say yes then every time after that it will appear the same when when opened.  This will give you more viewing area per field.  However, I do agree with HansUp, this is best controlled via a form.  Here is a snapshot of a table with more room per row.

[image]

The same can be done with query results.

Comment: Sorry that isn't what I was looking for. Thanks for your effort though